# Average for last 6 cells which are greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I have the challenge that my list will get every month new data.
I need now to get the average of the last 6 months (where the cell is bigger than 0).
My list gets every month new data and I need to get the average calculated for the last 6 months.

Example:
In January I need the average in cell V2 of the last 6 months (means Jul-Dez column K-P) or the last 6 cells which are bigger than 0 in column H-S
In February I need the average in cell V2 of the last 6 months (means Aug-Jan column L-Q) or the last 6 cells which are bigger than 0 in column H-S

Can someone help me?

Example list

[image]

I tried this:

`=AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER(H2:S2,ISNUMBER(H2:S2)),-6))`

But that gives me not the result I need.

I have now tried this formula from @rory
=AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER(H2:S2,H2:S2>0),-6))

BUT when I add new data into Jan then I get a different average result (see picture below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes that your columns are `H:S` and that your column headers are real `EOM` dates that you show formatted as `mmm-dd`

- we create a list of the columnNames so as to be able to detect the position of the column name that is one month before `TODAY()`
- then, using `CHOOSECOLS` create a list of all the entries in the row up to last month
- `FILTER` that row to remove any zero's, then average the last six (6).

  - *If there will never be no zero's in the months to be examined, the formula can be simplified*

**Formula edited as column headers are "real dates" at EOM and not text strings**

```
=LET(
    cols, Sheet3!$H$1:$S$1,
    lastCol, XLOOKUP(EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1), cols, cols),
    chkRng, CHOOSECOLS(Sheet3!$H2:$S2, SEQUENCE(, XMATCH(lastCol, Sheet3!$H$1:$S$1, 0))),
    notZero, FILTER(chkRng, chkRng <> 0),
    avg, AVERAGE(TAKE(notZero, , -6)),
    avg
)
```

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfeld, I am not working with table names.

Comment: @RogerErne your example looks like a table. If it is not then what exactly do you have for column headers so that we can tell what date the values correspond to?

Comment: Hi Ron Rosenfeld, the column header has dates in it (always the last day of a month) Like 30.04.2023, 31.05.2023, 30.06.2023 and so one.

Comment: @RogerErne So they are real dates but formatted to look like `mmm-yy`?

Comment: @RogerErne If that is the case, it is merely a matter of changing how we determine `lastCol`. Please see my edited post for that change. I assumed, as you mentioned, that it would always be the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

### Average of Last *n* Positive Cells

- It is assumed that the first column is always `H`, the last column is currently `S` and the result is currently in `V` i.e. there is an offset of 3 between the last and the result.
- It is expected that you will be inserting columns before (to the left of) 2 (`3-1`) columns to the left (currently `T`) of the result.

```
=LET(data,H2:V2,col_offset,3,last_cells,6,
    s,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)-col_offset),
    i,INDEX(data,,s),
    t,TAKE(i,-last_cells),
AVERAGE(FILTER(t,t>0,0)))
```

[image]

- If you meant to return the average of columns `M:R` (instead of `N:S`), simply increase the column offset to 4.
- If the data is in an Excel table, use `Table1[@[1]:[Result]]` instead of `H2:V2`.

Comment: Hi VBasic2008, when IO use your formula then it works for the data in my example from Jul - Dec

Comment: It does not work when I add new data in Jan (which should then calculate Aug - Jan)

Answer (score 0):

To check if they are greater than 0:

```
=AVERAGE(TAKE(FILTER(H2:S2,H2:S2>0),,-6))
```

Comment: Hi Rory, when IO use your formula then it works for the data in my example from Jul – Dec, It does not work when I add new data in Jan (which should then calculate Aug - Jan)

Comment: The formula doesn't care about dates. It just takes the last 6 values in columns H:S that are greater than 0.

Comment: Hi Rory, see above when I use your formula. When I add data in Jan than the last 6-month average is not correctly calculated based on the average Excel says at the bottom.

Comment: @RogerErne Apologies - I misread your original formula, which was actually taking the last 6 **rows**, not columns, as you were missing a comma. I have amended my formula above.